# Parsing Asterix in Qt, why do I need type conversion?

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, type-conversion

I am currently writing a parser for Asterix Cat 240 (Open standard for transmitting radar video data) and it works perfectly, but I do not know, why do I need type conversion?

```
rawAsterix.videoHR = static_cast<quint8>(buffer->at(i));
rawAsterix.videoHR = (rawAsterix.videoHR << 8) + static_cast<quint8>(buffer->at(i+1));
rawAsterix.videoHR = (rawAsterix.videoHR << 8) + static_cast<quint8>(buffer->at(i+2));
rawAsterix.videoHR = (rawAsterix.videoHR << 8) + static_cast<quint8>(buffer->at(i+3));
i+=4
```

buffer is a `QByteArray`, whish holds the data received by `QUdpSocket`.
At first I had no type conversion whish resulted (sometimes not every time) in strange behaviour. Why is that so?

Comment: define "sometimes not every time" and "strange behaviour". Do you have a self-contained test that can be used to analyse what is going wrong?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @rubenvb I cannot see any logic in the strange behaviour its just that some bits have not the right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QByteArray::at()` returns `char`. And `static_cast<quint8>` of this char returns `unsigned char`. It seems that in this code you need unsigned value.

In fact, the standard does not specify if plain `char` is signed or unsigned (see [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/2707359)). But if you need to be sure that you add unsigned value, you need to use `static_cast<quint8>` here.

Comment: Thank you that actually makes sense!